# Getting error "code will never execute" when using do-while loop for password checking function in c++e

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode10

I put a do/while loop in my password function but it doesn't work. I use xcode10 to code c++ and when I use a semicolon after the while statement it shows an error saying code will never execute

```
string password (string g)
{
    string ch = "hello" ;
    cout << "Enter password";
    getline(cin, g);
    do {
        if (ch.compare(g) != 0) {
            cout << " INCORRECT PASSWORD";
            return (0);
        } else {
            cout << "correct password";
            return (string(g));
        }
    } while (ch.compare(g) == 0);  //this is where it shows the error that the code will never exec
}
```

I wanted to put this loop and a few other things so I can make this a infinite loop till you enter the correct password.

Comment: So when do you think that `while` condition will be executed? Also, `return (0);` for constructing `std::string` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your `if` statement you will return in both cases causing the function to stop so it will never get to the while condition to test it

```
  string password(string g)
{
    string ch = "hello";
    cout << "Enter password\n";
    do
    {
        getline(cin, g);

        if (ch.compare(g) != 0)
        {
            cout << " INCORRECT PASSWORD\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "correct password";
            return (string(g));
        }
    } while (ch.compare(g) != 0);  
}
```

Comment: hey! so I removed the return function from if and else, its still not working. the do while loop. if I enter the correct password it continues, it I enter the wrong password then the output displays incorrect password and stops. it displays incorrect password and its like this. 
Enter password no
Incorrect Password (11db). 
I am using Xcode for c++.

Answer (score 0):

There is Return statement in the "`if`" and also in the "`else`".
You can see that no matter what will be the result of `ch.compare(g)`, the function will return to it's caller.

That's why it will never do the "`while`".

Try to set the Return statements in different place in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you get input at all too, in case of `EOF`.

```
string password() { // you don't need g as parameters in, your overwriting it
    string const ch = "hello"; // make ch const to show it not supposed to change
    cout << "Enter password";
    string g; // defining g here since now you need it
    while (getline(cin, g)) { // check that the read from cin is OK
        if (ch != g) { // simple notation for comparing two strings. There's also == available
            cout << "INCORRECT PASSWORD. Please try again\n"; // no return if you want to try again
        } else {
            cout << "correct password";
            return g; // you could also return ch here since they have the same content
        }
    }
    cout << "Unable to read line. aborting\n"; // not really a lot you can do if there is no input to read.
    return string(); // returning empty string.
}
```